# Segmentation Fault in my solution to SPOJ - The Next Palindrome

Tags: c

This is my solution to the SPOJ problem - [The Next Palindrome](http://www.spoj.com/problems/PALIN/).

I try to run it, but every time I input a no. like 9XXXXX..., it gives seg. fault, for example -

```
    $ ./a.exe
    1
99999

Palin string i++: 99999
Non-Palin String: 99999
Palin string i++: 99999
Non-Palin String: 99999
Palin string i++: 99999
Non-Palin String: 99999
Change string: 99999
9 Palin String: 99099
Palin Str j = 2
Palin Str j-- = 1
9 Palin String: 90099
Palin Str j = 1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

My code -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 1000000

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int t;
    scanf("%u",&t);
    
    unsigned long int i,j,k,len,change;
    char str[MAX];
    while(t--){                             //For every test case
        scanf("%s",str);
        i = 0;
        change = 0;
        len = strlen(str) - 1;
        Recheck:
        while(i <= (len/2)){                //If the input no. is a palindrome, then don't change it, else change it
            if(str[i] != str[len-i]){       //Compare 1st & last digit, then 2nd & 2nd last, so on....., if not same, then...
                if(str[i] > str[len-i]){    //if 1st digit > last digit,
                    str[len-i] = str[i];    //then make last one the same as 1st one 
                    i++;
                    change++;
                }
                else if(str[i] < str[len-i]){   //if <, then make the last one same as 1st one,
                    str[len-i] = str[i];        //but also increment it's left digit,
                    j = (len-i) - 1;            //if required, the next one too, and so on...
                    while(j >= 0){              //j moves from right to left (digits) in the string
                        if(str[j] != '9'){
                            str[j]++;
                            change++;
                            break;
                        }
                        else if(str[j] == '9'){
                            str[j] = '0';
                            if(j == 0){                 //If the no. becomes like 9......'\0'
                                for(k=len+1;k>=0;k--)   //and we need to increment, so shift the elements,
                                    str[k+1] = str[k];  //and make the string: 00.......'\0
                                str[0] = '0';           //Next loop will make str[0] = 1 & break.
                                len++;
                                j++;
                            }
                            change++;
                        }
                        printf("\n9 Non-Palin String: %s",str);
                        j--;
                    }
                    
                    if(j <= i)              //if the change reaches even before from where we compared(in 1st half, that is, i),
                        i = j;              //then change i to j, so that the no. can be checked again from j, as changes are till j.
                    else
                        i++;
                }
            }
            else if(str[i] == str[len-i]){  //No change to a palindrome
                printf("\nPalin string i++: %s",str);
                i++;
            }
            printf("\nNon-Palin String: %s",str);
        }
        
        if(change==0){              //change == 0 means that the no. was already a palindrome
            printf("\nChange string: %s",str);  //so we have to find the next no. which is a palindrome
            if(len%2)
                j = (len/2) + 1;
            else
                j = len/2;
            
            if(str[j] == '9'){      //So, if the mid char(s) is/are 9 then change the no. as we did before
                while(j >= 0){
                    if(str[j] != '9'){
                        str[j]++;
                        change++;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(str[j] == '9'){
                        str[j] = '0';
                        if(j == 0){
                            for(k=len+1;k>=0;k--)
                                str[k+1] = str[k];
                            str[0] = '0';
                            len++;
                            j++;
                            printf("\nIncrement string");
                        }
                        change++;
                    }
                    printf("\n9 Palin String: %s",str);
                    printf("\nPalin Str j = %lu",j);
                    j -= 1;
                    printf("\nPalin Str j-- = %lu",j);
                }
                printf("\nPalin to Recheck: %s",str);
                i = j;
                goto Recheck;
            }
            else{               //else, just increment the mid char/s
                if(len%2){
                    str[j]++;
                    str[j-1]++;
                }
                else{
                    str[j]++;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("\n%s",str);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I've added comments to understand the code.
For every no., 9, 99, 999, etc. it gives segmentation fault error.

Comment: where did it go bang? What did gdb say?

Comment: Okay, I found a link to use gdb. It says - Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x004015a7 in main ()

Comment: you have to learn how to use gdb - compile your code with -g then run the app using gdb http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/

Comment: I used the link you suggested, and it says - Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x004015a7 in main () at thenextpalindrome1.c:81
81                                                                      str[k+1] = str[k];

Comment: You have allocated a 1 million byte array for user entry on the stack. Are you sure you can type that much by tomorrow?

Comment: It is a solution to a SPOJ problem, the inputted no. is upto a million.

Comment: 1000000 in text needs less than 10 chars in the numeric array, not 1 million.

Comment: @paver - so look t the value of k at line 81 when it goes bang

Comment: I'm storing the no. as a string and then manipulating it char-by-char.

Comment: Sorry, yes, the question you linked does indeed ask for an input of up to 1 million digits, in which case your array is 1 too short (terminator), But what is the size of the `stdin` input buffer?

Comment: @pm100 -Yes, I did and it seems that k has picked some unknown value, like 4294784937, & it keeps on decrementing.

Comment: @WeatherVane: What do you mean by "stdin input buffer"? Sir, I'm new to C language, still learning.

Answer (score 0):

It seems odd to write an answer to my own question, but still...

The problem with the solution is that the variable k is an `unsigned int`, so k is never < 0, hence the infinite loop.

Thanks to pm100 & Weather Vane for their help.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer but too much for a comment.

*What do you mean by "stdin input buffer"?* Your typing goes into a system *buffer* until you press "Enter" at which point the contents are transferred to your array `str` by `scanf()`. The `stream` used is a predefined system stream call `stdin`. You can use the similar file function `fscanf(stdin,"%s",str);` but `scanf()` is more convenient (and not a very desirable method for a string anyway). However, it is very unlikely that the system buffer can hold 1 million characters, so I suggest you build the string yourself, something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define MAX 1000000

int main(void)
{
    char str [MAX] = "";         // initialise string to the empty string
    int str_len = 0;             // length (and index into) str
    int c;
    do {
        c = getch ();            // gets a char but the type returned is int
        printf("%c", c);
        if (c != 13)
            str [str_len++] = c; // insert in array
    }
    while (c != 13 && str_len < MAX-1);
    str [str_len] = 0;          // terminate array
    printf("\n%s\n", str);
    printf("Length %d\n", str_len);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. What I was able to understand is that the input stream is stored in stdin, a buffer & scanf uses it to read. But one last question, when there is no character in the stdin, will it return 0?

Comment: No, it waits until there is enough typing to satisfy the format specification.

Comment: As been pointed out many times on SO, it is far better when reading a string to use `fgets(str, MAX, stdin)`. But one drawback is the final `newline` will be the last char of the string (before terminator).

Comment: Hmm... that's right. Thanks a lot. I've learned something new today. :)